# How can I make the list of exposed filters hide options with no existing nodes?

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal commerce, and I have a "Product Type" select field in the "Accessories" content type. There are 20+ options. In the views page I'm exposing that field, but I want only the options to display that have 1 or more nodes with that option selected. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this module when I was doing some search regarding your question.

[Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) seems to do just the same. As the module page mentions

> This module allows to have an exposed filter only show options that
>   belong to result set. The options are calculated real-time with the
>   current View's configuration, including the filters selected by the
>   user so you get dynamic dependent filters.

I haven't used this module personally. But this module is worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that can be done with views. Even if it can be done, I am sure it will take a considerable amount of coding and I am not sure if it will be performant enough(might reduce the performance).

This can be done easily with [Apache Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module.

> Faceted search is supported if you use the facet API module. Facets
>   will be available for you ranging from content author to taxonomy to
>   arbitrary fields.

When you enable facet API with apache solr module, you should get the facets(similar to filters). Facets will be displayed only if there are some results which have the value of the facet in their node.

**Note :** You will need to set up a Java server to have the Apache Solr running.